# Linux shell via serial console gives garbage output

Tags: linux, shell, serial

I connect to a router running OpenWRT via serial port. All shell output is broken as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlTMd.png) (missing symbols) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okfl8.png) (`ls /dev/` output — escape sequences shown and overall mess). The interesting thing is that kernel messages during boot seem ok. The serial port is definetely working as I tested it with numerous distributions and machines, so I guess it's OpenWRT problem. How do I fix that? BTW lowering the baudrate doesn't help.

Comment: You need to change your terminal type to one that is supported by the terminal or emulator that you use to connect.

Comment: I've tried to `export TERM=linux` (and `vt-102` and whatever), it doesn't help either. How do I know what type I need?

Comment: It will depend on whatever is on your local side. Usually `export TERM=xterm` will work, or you can try `dumb`. If you pipe your output through `cat` it will strip the escape sequences, allowing you to see sensible output until you find the right setting.

Comment: Pipe serial port through `hexdump` or `od`, figure out which control sequences are used, then set correct `TERM` (instead of guessing).

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved this issue. It was the kernel UART driver FIFO size issue. The hardware FIFO is 64 byte, but the driver was aware only of 32 bit or something.